# Can't register new Client ID on Instagram developers page

Tags: instagram, recaptcha

I can't register new client because always have a wrong captcha, I tried to create it with different browsers but same effect :(

> The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again.

[image: captcha always wrong]

Comment: Same problem here ... I tried in different environments and did not work at all.

Comment: "me too!" (saying that since I think this has gotten worse recently)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used the Content-Security-Policy extension for chrome.

https://github.com/PhilGrayson/chrome-csp-disable

Then the field appeared -> New App Created.

Comment: Thanks Jono your solution helps me.

Comment: Confirmed that this is the correct answer. I just tested the chrome extension enabled on that form and it's now showing a captcha. https://i.imgur.com/fSgfrWF.png

Answer (score 12):

The form is broken.

I've been trying it on and off for the last two weeks, also with different browsers, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I have exactly the same problem when trying to create an client ID. I've send in a ticket for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can see my answer there you have to install google chrome extension and then don't forgot to disable the  Content-security policy 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden

you see here too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188447/5889990