# Can't see Instagram captcha

Tags: instagram

When I try to register a new client, I don't see the captcha. What am I doing wrong? Is this a known issue? I tried it in Chrome, Chrome Incognito mode, FireFox, and Safari.

Answer (score 3):

download this extension on google chrome and  disable Content-Security-Policy  on Instagram thats works for me enjoy it !!!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden

Answer (score 1):

Open with Google Chrome and enable add-on Disable Content-Security-Policy. I have tried and succeeded. Hopefully helpful